# Using masonry.js in facebook app

Tags: facebook, jquery-masonry

I currently use masonry plugin in my facebook app. Everything is work well but except one thing, at the first time, the FB.autoGrow don't resize the iframe fast enough. As the result, the layout is broken, and all the items are overlapped as in the picture. Could you please tell me any solution to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried initializing the plugin with a little timeout?

Comment: I create a ajax paginator (load more), that is the main cause :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in github. I have just add these lines of code and it works well.

```
 bufferPx: 10000,
 extraScrollPx: 12000,
```

References:
https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/145